# Convert strings to emoji in python

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a collection of twits and i want to check emojis in them, but it looks like the writing procedure for the collection converted all emojis in string for example '' is ':-)' in text and '' is ':D' and so on with all emojis. If we try to check unicode codepoints for them we get `':-)'.encode('utf-8')` equals to `b':-)'` in the same time `''.encode('utf-8')` equals to `'b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x8a` and equality check fails. Using `utf-16` : `':-)'.encode('utf-16')` equals to `b'\xff\xfe:\x00-\x00)\x00'` and `''.encode('utf-16')` is `b'\xff\xfe=\xd8\n\xde'` . So is there any way to convert text representations such as ':-)' back to emoji ''.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is to search it with regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to convert any text emoticon back to emoji e.g. as follows:

```
>>> dict_emo = { ':-)'  : b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x8a',
...              ':)'   : b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x8a',
...              '=)'   : b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x8a',  # Smile or happy
...              ':-D'  : b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x83',
...              ':D'   : b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x83',
...              '=D'   : b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x83',  # Big smile
...              '>:-(' : b'\xF0\x9F\x98\xA0',
...              '>:-o' : b'\xF0\x9F\x98\xA0'   # Angry face
...              }
>>> print( dict_emo[':)'].decode('utf-8'))

>>> print( dict_emo['>:-('].decode('utf-8'))

>>> print( dict_emo[':-D'].decode('utf-8'))

>>>
>>>
>>> dict_emot= { ':-)'  : b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x8a'.decode('utf-8'),
...              ':)'   : b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x8a'.decode('utf-8'),
...              '=)'   : b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x8a'.decode('utf-8'),  # Smile or happy
...              ':-D'  : b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x83'.decode('utf-8'),
...              ':D'   : b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x83'.decode('utf-8'),
...              '=D'   : b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x83'.decode('utf-8'),  # Big smile
...              '>:-(' : b'\xF0\x9F\x98\xA0'.decode('utf-8'),
...              '>:-o' : b'\xF0\x9F\x98\xA0'.decode('utf-8')   # Angry face
...              }
>>> print( dict_emot[':)'] )

>>> print( dict_emot['>:-o'] )

>>> print( dict_emot['=D'] )

>>>
```

Unfortunately, there are at least two tasks remaining:

- [Text Smiley Faces and Their Meaning](http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/textmessageabbreviations_02.asp#smiley-meanings-5) are neither stable nor definitive, see also [Common examples of emoticons (Computer Definition)](http://www.yourdictionary.com/emoticon) and [List of emoticons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons) - although there are some attempts to create a [resource of all the text smileys and emoticons in the world](http://cool-smileys.com/text-emoticons);
- [Natural Language Processing: What is an algorithmic way to find all smileys in a text?](https://www.quora.com/Natural-Language-Processing-What-is-an-algorithmic-way-to-find-all-smileys-in-a-text) and how-to eliminate (false) *embedded* text emoticons like `:-)` *smile* in `:-))` *double chin*.